# Find largest and smallest numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm working on C++ program to  store random values in an array of size 1000.
Then program will ask user to enter 'X'  largest and 'Y' smallest numbers.
'X' and 'Y' are any integer values less than size of array.
Program will then output 'X' Largest and 'Y' smallest numbers from array.

Suppose array have 1  2  4  7  9  14  3

X=2

Y=3

Output will be

Largest 2 numbers in array are 14   9

Smallest 3 number in array are 1  2  3

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int size[1000];
   int x, y, max;
    max = 0;
    cout << "How many Largest numbers do you need ?\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "How many Smallest numbers do you need ?\n";
    cin >> y;
        for (int i = 0;i <= 999;i++)
        {
            size[i] = rand() % 100;
            cout << "No." << i << " = " << size[i] << endl;
        }
        for (int j = 1;j <= x;j++)
        {

            for (int i = 0;i <= 999;i++)
            {
                if (size[i] > max)
                    max = size[i];
            }
            cout << "LARGEST NUMBERS\n" << max << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorta related: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My question is above as i described below is the code i used to find value but it gives same value each time for example if I want 3 largest numbers it gives me same value. 99, 99 ,99

Comment: @1337 -- You didn't state what was wrong with your program in your subject.  Read your request again -- do you see a question?  But some questions for you -- can you sort the numbers?  If so, then the solution is much easier than what you're trying now.

Comment: @1337 -- Please print the numbers that are in your array.  You will see that there are duplicates, thus it is possible you will get 99, 99, 99, ... because you have 3 or more 99's in your array.   Thus there is no way your method is going to work without rethinking how to remove the duplicates.  Better to just store the numbers in a `std::set<int>` and just get the largest / smallest values.  A simple 4 line solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).  Since a `std::set` already sorts its entries, plus does not store duplicates the solution becomes very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>

int main()
{
   int size[1000];
   int x, y;
   std::cout << "How many Largest numbers do you need ?\n";
   std::cin >> x;
   std::cout << "How many Smallest numbers do you need ?\n";
   std::cin >> y;

   srand(0);  // seed random number

   // generate the numbers in the array
   std::generate(size, size + 1000, []{return rand() % 1000;});

   // create a std::set consisting of the numbers in the array
   std::set<int> intSet(size, size + 1000);
```

The `std::generate` function automatically "loops" and fills in the array with the random values.

The `std::set<int>` constructor simply creates a `std::set` using the values in your array.  Note that this will automatically sort and remove duplicate entries.

Once you have this, then it's just a matter of printing out the first `x` numbers and last `y` numbers in the `std::set`.

```
   // print the smallest numbers
   auto iter1 = intSet.begin();  // beginning of the set
   int i = 0;
   while (i < y)
   {
       std::cout << *iter1 << " ";
       ++iter1;
       ++i;
   }
   std::cout << "\n";

   // print the largest numbers
   auto iter2 = intSet.rbegin();  // end of the set.  We will loop backwards
   i = 0;
   while (i < x)
   {
       std::cout << *iter2 << " ";
       ++iter2;
       ++i;
   }
}
```

The largest numbers are printed going backwards from the end of the set, which is why the reverse iterator is used.

Note:  You will have to put checks in the loops that print out the values to ensure the iterators do not fall of the beginning and end of the set.  I leave that for you as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is likely coming from the fact that you are not resetting max after each iteration. It is hard to tell because you didn't really ask anything.

Try this:

```
    for (int j = 1;j <= x;j++)
    {
        max = size[0];
        for (int i = 1;i <= 999;i++)
        {
            if (size[i] > max)
                max = size[i];
        }
        cout << "LARGEST NUMBERS\n" << max << endl;
    }
```

Implement a similar nested for-loop for the minimum output.

This is a list based version that has been tested to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
  std::list<int> intList;
  int x, y;

  std::cout << "How many Largest numbers do you need ?\n";
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "How many Smallest numbers do you need ?\n";
  std::cin >> y;

  for (int i = 0;i <= 9;i++)
    {
      auto a = rand() % 100;
      intList.push_back(a);
      std::cout << "No." << i << " = " << a << std::endl;
    }
  for (auto j = intList.end(); j != intList.begin();)
    {
      std::cout << "Listdump: " << *--j << std::endl;
    }

  intList.sort();
  int count2x = 0;
  for (auto j = intList.end(); j != intList.begin();)
    {
      if (count2x == x) {break;}
      std::cout << "LARGEST NUMBERS\n" << *--j << std::endl;
      count2x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'size[i] = rand() % 100;' is only going to give you values between 0 and 99. see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: giving me same value for every largest value.

Comment: Honestly, you should just use a container like std::List which has a built in sort function. You can call List.sort() and pull the first x and y elements off list, no need for nested loop.

Comment: You are probably missing the additional clause in the if statement ' || max == -1'

Comment: You are right... you can make an int array with size[x] and use that to store each next largest value, checking that it is not already stored in that int array.

Comment: Why did you use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`?  Then simply call `std::sort(intList.begin(), intList.end());`

Comment: @paulMcKenzie, `std::vector` doesn't have a built in sort() function, but fair enough, that std::sort works. Doesn't matter on this small of input much anyway.

Comment: @Zroach -- There is a "built-in" sort function -- it's called `std::sort`.  This also would work for the array the OP is using, instead of introducing a `std::list` that uses more memory.  `std::sort(size, size + 1000);`  would have sorted the OP's original array.

Comment: Yes, yours is better. I would probably use a vector. - Feel free to edit the answer. I can't at the moment.